# Adding a Javascript Array To a Numbered List

Tags: javascript, html

I have a predefined array list that I need to be formatted into a numbered list in HTML. I'm very new to html with javascript and am having a hard time with dom manipulation

here is my js code `var fruits = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Pineapples', 'Mangos'];`

here is my html

```
<div id="fruits">



        </div>

            <h3>Fruits</h3>
```

`

its very bare bones and that's simply because I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **DOM** like below. This code loops through your array, and adds each element to an ordered list.

```js
var fruits = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Pineapples', 'Mangos'];
var listOfFruits = [];
var list = document.getElementById("list");


fruits.forEach(function(element) {
  listOfFruits.push("<li>" + element + "</li>");
});

list.innerHTML = listOfFruits.join('');
```

```html
<ol id="list"></ol>
```

Or you can use **jQuery** like below. This code loops through your array and appends a `<li>` to your html.

```js
var fruits = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Pineapples', 'Mangos'];
var listOfFruits = [];


fruits.forEach(function(element) {
  listOfFruits.push("<li>" + element + "</li>");
});

$("#list").html(listOfFruits.join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="list"></ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate an array of html elements and display it :

```js
var fruits = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Pineapples', 'Mangos'];

var elems = fruits.map(element => `<li>${element}</li>`);

document.querySelector('#fruitsList').innerHTML = elems.join('');
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
<ul id="fruitsList"></ul>
```

to display the numbers either use `<ol>` or `<ul>` with `list-style-type: decimal;`