# Javascript: Orderlist items In Table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-lists

I am working on task using javascript in table.I am trying to add order-list but stuck in that code. when clicking a button a table is displaying that i have achieve.but the thing it should display with numericals i need to add order-list also.Please anyone who can help me to solve these.Taking [Inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837224/adding-a-javascript-array-to-a-numbered-list)  from here, But my code is not working [codepen](https://codepen.io/asiyaf09/pen/eYNLpRg).Please someone point me in right direction.

**Output:**[image]

Thanks in Advance.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <h3>JavaScript Programming</h3>
 <hr/>  
 <input type="button" onclick="f1()" value="Get Data"  />
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <table id="table1"  border="2"> 
 </table>
 
 <script> 
  function  f1() {
   var  ar = ["HTML5", "CSS3", "JavaScript", "Angular JS", "Node JS", "Express JS"];
      
   var  str  =  "";
   for(var i  in  ar)
   {
    str =  str  +   "<tr><td>" +  ar[i]  +  "  </td> </tr>";
   }
      
   var obj = document.getElementById("table1");
   obj.innerHTML  = str;
  } 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must first define  **listOfList** as array

```
 const listOfList = []
```

and second  change **element** by **ar[i]**

```
listOfList.push("<li>" + ar[i] + "</li>");
```

```js
function f1() {
    const listOfList = [];
    const ar = ["HTML5", "CSS3", "JavaScript", "Angular JS", "Node JS", "Express JS"];
   

    let str = "";
    for (let i in ar) {
        str = str + "<tr><td>" + (+i+1)+ "."+ ar[i] + "  </td> </tr>";
        listOfList.push("<li>" + ar[i] + "</li>");
    }

    const obj = document.getElementById("table1");
    obj.innerHTML = str;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <h3>JavaScript Programming</h3>
 <hr/>  
 <input type="button" onclick="f1()" value="Get Data"  />
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <table id="table1"  border="2"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response and effort, its almost  near what i want but List should come inside that table.

Comment: @AsiyaFatima you want the  list as element of table ?

Comment: yes, the numbers should come in serial order accordingly in that table.

Comment: @AsiyaFatima try now

Comment: I have updated code added the ouput exactly want I have to achieve.

Comment: @AsiyaFatima ,just remove all elements related of list in html and js as well

Comment: yeah, Done with that .i achieve exactly want i need ,thanks